# I and trying to create an Editor Window UI in VSIX Extension VS2022

Tags: editor, visual-studio-2022, vsix

I want to create my own bespoke Window/Form or whatever you call it, in a Vsix Extension project. I want to have it work like a document in the document window but it is not a document but like the manage nuget packages window with my own UI. I think I need to create a ToolWindowPane but I don't know how to register and display it. Information is so scarce.

I am using VS2022 and have the Community tools installed and Extensibility Essentials 2022 and I am on the latest release of VS 2022. What would be good is if there is an example project of someone doing this but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 0):

The latest VSSDK Wizards default to creating toolwindows that are based on WPF, rather that WinForms. But you can still use a WinForms based UserControl for your toolwindow content.

The easiest way to do this would be to construct a new VSIX Package (not using the community templates), Then add a ToolWindow to the package via the Add Item dialog. Then add a WinForm User Control.

Find the ToolWindow class that's derived from ToolWindowPane, comment out the assignment to the Content property in the constructor, and then add an override for the IWin32Window Window property, and have it create your user control:

For example:

```
override public IWin32Window Window
{
    get
    {
        if (control == null) 
        { 
            control = new MyWinformsBasedUserControl(this);
        }
        return (IWin32Window)control;
    }
}
```

with control being a private member of your ToolWindow class.

Sincerely,

Comment: Thanks' Ed. I know that I can create a WinForms alternative but I prefer to use WPF for a number of reasons. Finding any information on this topic is like walking through a desert to find water. I will continue my search but may also just convert it to WinForms. However, I am sure where is a resource dictionary out there.

Comment: If you want to use WPF, then the default VSSDK template is a good starting point. There is a nice set of community templates, but you may want to just to use the VSSDK template to start, as a lot of the functionality can be a bit obscured by the community templates. Also, there is a repository of samples on github that may be helpful as well: https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples